# TypeScript pass props to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am quite new at TypeScript and I am trying to send some `props` to a `children`, normally I will do it like this, - Maybe this is not the best way.

app.js

```
import React form 'react'
import Component from './component'

const App = () => {

  const myfunc1 = () => 'some function 1'
  const myfunc2 = () => 'some function 2'
  const myfunc3 = () => 'some function 3'
  const var1 = 'some variable 1'
  const var2 = 'some variable 2'

  return (
    <Component 
      myfunc1={myfunc1}
      myfunc2={myfunc2}
      myfunc3={myfunc3}
      var1={var1}
      var2={var2}
    />
  )

}
```

component.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Component = ({
  myfunc1,
  myfunc2,
  myfunc3,
  var1,
  var2,
}) => (
   <>
    // Use the props on the component
   </>
)

export default Component
```

But when doing it with TypeScript, it asks for type declarations on all `props` on `Component`.

Is there a better simpler way to pass `props` so I do not have to declare the type on all `props`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';


type Props = {
  // types...
}

const Component: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  myfunc1,
  myfunc2,
  myfunc3,
  var1,
  var2,
}) => (
<>
</>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this requires me to declare all types for the `props`, what would it be for say a function?

Comment: Yes. Occupational hazard of TS. You have to type that stuff! Use `Function` type

Comment: You can also just do: `const Component = (props: Props) => ()` but then TS doesn't know about props such as `children`. This way, your `Props` extends the standard React Props type

Comment: If your question is about generally typing all you props, then yes. It is best to declare all types! This is what is attractive about using TS in React. You mentioned you are new to this, give it time. On any real project this will be well worth the effort and verbosity!